Chalk method for planing?
If a hand plane can flatten a surface twice the length of its sole, I’m wondering if this method would work: Apply chalk to the entire surface of a board to be flattened, then playing across the surface of the board. Where the chalk would remain on low spots, identifying all the high spots.

I've seen many people use a pencil scribble across the face of a board to ensure even sanding. I'm sure that would work for planing, too, and with much less mess than chalk.


If a hand plane can flatten a surface twice the length of its sole

A hand plane can flatten a surface substantially longer than twice the length of its sole. Think boardroom table and a no. 7 in the Stanley numbering system.
It's been said before that if you absolutely had to you could flatten large panels or long boards using only a block plane. It's very much not ideal, but it is doable.

I’m wondering if this method would work: Apply chalk to the entire surface of a board to be flattened, then playing across the surface of the board. Where the chalk would remain on low spots, identifying all the high spots.

What you describe is in essence one of the established ways to identify low spots. The plane itself finds the high spots if it's not too short for the job since that's basically how longer planes work — see the old Stanley graphic in this previous Answer. The associated text might give you some insights into what you're looking to do.

Thank you for your reply! As someone trying to learn how to do this, please forgive me if my questions sound stupid. If you were flattening an 8' by 3' wide slab of walnut using only a plane, how long would the process take? The other question is, if you were using a much shorter plane like a No. 4 plane to flatten a slab, what's the best approach to take? Would you divide the board up into several sections first? After you planed each section flat, how would you bring them to the same thickness?

"...how long would the process take?" That's a how long is a piece of string? question. It depends on the user, the plane, how sharp the iron is (and how much that's maintained), the steel or heat treating of the iron (better steels need honing less often), the grain in the wood, the hardness of the specific piece of walnut (wood is a natural material so it varies way more than the textbooks tend to suggest). "The other question is, if you were using a much shorter plane like a No. 4 plane to flatten a slab, what's the best approach to take?" This is touched on in the linked Answer [contd]

...but a fuller response is beyond the scope of the Comments system here. It would be better to watch and listen to multiple people people flattening slabs, workbench tops and other large surfaces with varied planes and noting the various little technique differences each employ to get to the same end point. There will nearly always be some use of winding sticks, often but not always a straightedge of some description, but the actual planing side of it can be more varied that one might guess.

Thank you for your time and replies. I am having a horrible time identifying high spots because I lost my vision and can’t use winding sticks. I’m really at a loss for what to do.

What would be the steps for flattening a 2‘ x 4‘ surface area using only a block plane?

Comments aren't for extended follow-on discussion, so we have to leave it at this. Plus the details necessary to give a proper answer are really beyond the room available anyway. But the basics are covered in the linked Answer — you identify high spots and plane them off, then keep doing that until the surface is essentially fully flat. How much effort and time any planing job would take is really down to how badly out of flat it is to begin with, along with all the other variables identified, and this gets exaggerated if the plane is so small. But without use of windings sticks and [contd]

.... a straightedge (used across, along the length and checking both diagonals) it's probably not possible to do this successfully every time, especially hard if the surface has a pronounced twist — in traditional English parlance warp is called "wind" which is where winding sticks get their name, as they are to help remove "winding" or twist. It's very difficult to get a board or panel that had some twist even close to perfect without them.
